# alternative for not using 'async: false' for a sequential $.getjson call

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, getjson

### **UPDATE: rewrote the question to highlight my expected result**

**Want I want to do:**

1. loop through sequential json link into a array --- from 1.json to 100.json
2. add # to arr[n][0] to store the n.json # --- arr[0][0] = 1 for 1.json, arr[1][0] = 2 for 2.json
3. find the longest array and get it's header by $.getjson --- so I must finish arr[] capture first
4. show final table based on info. I got from step 2 & 3.

i.e. first: getjson1 -> second: find longest array and getjson2 -> third: showtable

This can be done by using async: false, but the peformance is bad. I'm looking for an alternative to get same result.

---

**Without 'async: false', the problems are:**

- loading arr[] takes longer time that step 3 & 4
- fail to mark 1 into the array[0][0] that arr[0] stored 1.json data
- I'm okay to store 7.json data into arr[0], but need to make sure arr[0][0] = 7

> expected result
>
> > read 1.json -> write '1' into arr[0][0] first -> write 1.json data into arr[0][1],  arr[0][2]
> > read 2.json -> write '2' into arr[1][0] first -> write 2.json data into arr[1][1],  arr[1][2], arr[1][3]

> problematic result: wrote 7.json data into arr[0] and marked arr[0][0] as '1', I suspect it's based on which .json completes first
>
> > write '1' into arr[0][0] first ----> pushed 7.json data into arr[0][1],  arr[0][2], arr[0][3]
> > write '2' into arr[1][0] first ----> pushed 6.json data into arr[1][1],  arr[1][2]

---

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer, running each AJAX sequentially:**

I'd thought you wanted to run all of the AJAX operations at the same time and just have a single follow-up operation, but from comments it sounds like you want to await each AJAX operation individually.  You just don't want them to be blocking, of course.

Since we're dealing with a Promise interface, you can still `await` it.  Still return the `Promise` from the function:

```
function readdata(i) {
  return $.getJSON(
    // no changes here
  )
}
```

But now, instead of adding each one to an array, you'll `await` each one.  And do all of this inside of an `async` IIFE so you can use the `await` keyword.  Since each one is awaited, you'd then just run your follow-up operation afterward.  For example:

```
(async function () {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    await readdata(i);
  }
  showtable();
})();
```

This has a similar effect to your previous "async: false" approach in that each operation has to complete before the next one can continue.  But the main difference is that this approach doesn't block the UI so the user doesn't feel the effect.

---

**Original Answer, running all AJAX simultaneously:**

I think jQuery's AJAX operations return a Promise interface, so they should be awaitable.  If that's the case, return that Promise from `readdata`:

```
function readdata(i) {
  return $.getJSON(
    // no changes here
  )
}
```

Then when calling that function in your loop, add those returned Promises to an array:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  promises.push(readdata(i));
}
```

Now that you have an array of Promises, you can wait for all of them to finish before proceeding:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
  showtable();
});
```

The benefit here is that you're not blocking on each AJAX operation individually, or even waiting on each AJAX operation individually.  They all trigger at once and run as simultaneously as the browser can manage.  You're just not running your follow-up operation until all of them have completed.

Comment: Thanks David. 
It looks almost can solve my questions, but I just tried, it doesn't read 1.json correctly into arr[0] (probably pushed the earliest finished getjson into [0]), any way to fix this.
Besides, I edited the question a bit to add 1 more step.

Comment: @ChanTaiMan: What specifically do you mean by "it doesn't read 1.json correctly into arr[0]"?  Is the AJAX request made?  Is the response what you expect?  When you step through the code in the browser's debugger, what specifically happens?  Is this a separate issue than the one you were asking about in the question?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear.

I want to read data synchronously from 0 to 10.
read 1.json -> write '1' into arr[0][0] first -> write 1.json data into arr[0][1],  arr[0][2], arr[0][3]
read 2.json -> write '2' into arr[1][0] first -> write 2.json data into arr[1][1],  arr[1][2], arr[1][3]

but now with your solution, data read in random order maybe 7.json finished the ealiest.
write '1' into arr[0][0] first ----> pushed 7.json data into arr[0][1],  arr[0][2], arr[0][3]
write '2' into arr[1][0] first ----> pushed 6.json data into arr[1][1],  arr[1][2], arr[1][3]

Comment: @ChanTaiMan: Oh, so you want the operations to always run one after the other, not simultaneously?

Comment: @ChanTaiMan: I've updated the answer with a fully sequential version.

Comment: I don't mind if data comes in one after the other from performance standpoint, but it's a must for me to capture which n.json I'm capturing, so I need to put the number in every arr[n][0]. It's okay to read 7.json first, then 6 then 1, but I need to make sure arr[n][0] are 7, 6, 1 not 1, 2, 3.

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance & answer, but I cannot 100% get how does the async work. I rewrote my whole question and hope it's now more specific and easier to understand.

Comment: @ChanTaiMan: What do you mean by "cannot 100% get how does the async work"?  Have you done any research or walked through any tutorials on async/await in JavaScript?  When you attempt and test this approach, what specifically do you try and what specifically doesn't work as expected?